# Add preloader to this JQuery.post() script

Tags: jquery

I am using following code to get relevant search result :

```
<form>
<input id="message" type="text" name="search" value=""/>  
</form>

<div id="searchresults" class="contentbox"></div> 
<div id="noresult" class="contentbox" style="display:none">no results found.</div>


function getticketsuggestions() { 
    currentcheckcontent = $("#message").val();
    if (currentcheckcontent) {
        $.post("submitticket.php", { action: "getkbarticles", text: currentcheckcontent },
        function(data){                                      
            if (data) {               
                $("#searchresults").html(data);                
                $('#noresult').hide();
                $("#searchresults").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else {
            $('#noresult').fadeIn(3000); 
            $("#searchresults").hide();
            }
        });
        lastcheckcontent = currentcheckcontent;
    } 
        setTimeout('getticketsuggestions();', 3000);                
}
getticketsuggestions();
```

This code works perfect. I get all search result inside `<div id="searchresults">`

I want to add **Preloader "loading..."** while fetching result from submitticket.php

How can I achieve this ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `.ajaxStart()` + `.ajaxStop()` handlers, which will fire globally for all ajax request you're gonna send. So you may show and hide some `DIV` or whatever here.

Your second option is use the underlaying `.ajax()` call instead of `$.post()`. Within here can can overwrite `beforeSend` and `complete` handlers to do the same thing, showing & hiding some info.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
   url:   "submitticket.php",
   data: {
      action: "getkbarticles",
      text: currentcheckcontent
   },
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'html',
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       $('#info').show();  // #info must be defined somehwere
   },
   success: function(data){
       if (data) {               
            $("#searchresults").html(data);                
            $('#noresult').hide();
            $("#searchresults").fadeIn('slow');
        }
   },
   complete: function(xhr, textStatus){
        $('#info').hide();  // #info must be defined somehwere
   }
});
```

Ref.: [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't want to use .ajax() for some reason you could do this with your code:

```
$('#someDiv').html('loading...');    
$.post("submitticket.php", { action: "getkbarticles", text: currentcheckcontent },
    function(data){                                      
        if (data) {               
            $("#searchresults").html(data);                
            $('#noresult').hide();
            $("#searchresults").fadeIn('slow');

        }
        else {
        $('#noresult').fadeIn(3000); 
        $("#searchresults").hide();
        }
    $('#someDiv').html('');
    });
```

Comment: @ Moin : I have already tried doing this but $('#someDiv').html(''); keeps on show<->hide due to SetTimeout